# Firebase SSE (server-sent events) REST. Monitor + Write on same connection

Tags: firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database

I'm doing this test with an ESP8266 wifi module.
I want to keep a connection stablished continuosly with Google Firebase, to monitor for changes in values of the database and also to be able to write to it, and be able to do both operations on the same connection. Is that possible? Because doing the things separated they work.

This is my test database:

[image]

***SITUATION 1 - WORKS - MONITOR***

(1) Open TCP/SSL connection to eletronica-ab6b1.firebaseio.com, port 443.
(2) Send the following HTTP packet:

`GET /database333.json?auth=DZSQwLoNWAneWA9BcEfAgnelmY965pq98HF4pITU HTTP/1.1
Host: eletronica-ab6b1.firebaseio.com
Accept: text/event-stream
LINE FEED`

(3) Doing this, I do receive a notification whenever 'val' is changed, and a keep-alive packet is sent by Google every 30 secodnds. This works.

***SITUATION 2 - WORKS - WRITE***

(1) Open TCP/SSL connection to eletronica-ab6b1.firebaseio.com, port 443.
(2) Send the following HTTP packet:

`PATCH /database333.json?auth=DZSQwLoNWAneWA9BcEfAgnelmY965pq98HF4pITU HTTP/1.1
Host: eletronica-ab6b1.firebaseio.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 13
"LINE FEED"
{"val":"555"}`

(3) Doing this, value "555" is correctly written the database.

***SITUATION 3 - DOESN'T WORK - TRY TO MIX THEM***

(1) Open TCP/SSL connection to eletronica-ab6b1.firebaseio.com, port 443.
(2) Send the first HTTP packet:

`GET /database333.json?auth=DZSQwLoNWAneWA9BcEfAgnelmY965pq98HF4pITU HTTP/1.1
Host: eletronica-ab6b1.firebaseio.com
Accept: text/event-stream
LINE FEED`

(3) At this point I am monitoring for changes in the database, and receiving a keep-alive packet from Google every 30 seconds. Ok until here.
(4) And then I send the following HTTP packet, trying to write to the database:
"

`PATCH /PIC.json?auth=DZSQwLoNWAneWA9BcEfAgnelmY965pq98HF4pITU HTTP/1.1
Host: eletronica-ab6b1.firebaseio.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 13
LINE FEED
{"val":"333"}`

(5) Doing this, I have tried to write in the database using the same connection, but the write operation did not worked.

Do somebody know what I'm doing incorrect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Listening and writing to the Firebase Realtime Database through its streaming REST API will require two separate connections. There is no way to perform the write operations over the same connection as the continuous read operation.

---

*Some more details*

Firebase Realtime Database's streaming REST API is implemented using the REST Server-Sent Events protocol (SSE). SSE is unidirectional: each connection either sends data *or* receives data, but not both.

Being based on SSE This significantly simplifies its implementation on existing HTTP environments, when compared to for example the bi-directional web socket protocol, which Firebase Realtime Database uses for its internal SDK-to-server communications.

Also see:

- MDN's article on [SSE/EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource)
- HTML5Rocks' article on [streaming updates with Server-Sent Events](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/)

Comment: are you 100% sure?

Comment: I added some more info on why this is the case.